# windows 8 stack issue with mingw

Tags: windows, compiler-construction, mingw

I have a problem with stack overflow using C++ (mingw compiler) under Windows8. It is only 64 MB. I don't know how to change it.
I tried to write

```
#pragma comment(linker,"/STACK:512000000")
```

it doesn't help
Also, I tried compile my program

```
g++ -Wl,--stack=512000000 a.cpp -o a.exe
```

It also doesn't help. However in Windows 7 and XP it works as I remember.
Can somebody help?

Comment: What is the problem you run into using `-Wl,--stack=512000000`?  Also, 512MB is a lot of stack - I suppose the system might just be having trouble finding a contiguous block of available address space when you try to run the program. Are you sure you don't simply have a bug that's causing the stack overflow?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the default value is 64M under windows 8, it's far too larger than necessary. And claiming 512M is just wrong, try heap (use malloc() or Win32APIs like LocalAlloc() etc.)